# Can't find an element on iOS in my xamarin ui tests

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I wrote some tests on android and now I'm trying to make it compatible to iOS too.

I have some picker :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHBH1.png)

I gave the picker automation id and also to the label inside him so I can read it text,

in android I succeed but in iOS I can't even see the label.

tree repl in iOS :
[Ios repl tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugDFA.png)

tree repl in android:
[android repl tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZUxR.png)

the xaml code:

```
                    <scrControls:ScrPickerWithBorder
                        x:Name="SleepStartPicker"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0"
                        ArrowColor="{StaticResource LableTextColor}"
                        AutomationId="SleepStartPicker"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource EntryBackgoundLite}"
                        BorderColor="#C9D0D5"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding SleepStartOptions}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSleepStartIndex}"
                        TextColor="{StaticResource EntryTextColor}"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        TextAutomationId="HouseholdScrStartPickerLabel"/>
```

why this is happening ?
how can I read the label's text ?

Comment: Hi, do you mean the **HouseholdScrStartPickerLable** not be shown when testing in iOS device, and could you share the Xaml code of Forms? I will check that.

Comment: I shared the xaml code

Comment: Hi, I have tried that, however can not find `TextAutomationId` used in `Picker`.