# How can I get to the text via automation id?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I can't get to the label text value,
in android the label have automation id but in iOS it dissapear and I don't know why I wrote post about this also and didn't get an answer:
[Can't find an element on iOS in my xamarin ui tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552861/cant-find-an-element-on-ios-in-my-xamarin-ui-tests)
so I'm trying something different now:
[Somebody knows how can I get the text in the image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjOpI.png)

thanks for the help

Comment: What means of  `disappear` ?  If you want to get element in native iOS ,you could use `AccessibilityIdentifier`  property .

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/